# Convert to comment results in oops! something bad happened error.

Tags: bug, status-completed, convert-to-comment

Trying to convert [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/153624/access-localhost-on-mac-os-x-from-parallels-machine/309563#309563) to comment results in oops! something bad happened error.

Actual error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Huh, if I click to edit the post, I get a "post cannot be loaded" error, and its revisions page [doesn't exist](http://superuser.com/posts/309563/revisions). But only for that post. Something odd has happened... Also, there does seem to be a matching comment, so that part has maybe worked. I'm tempted to try deleting it (to see if that works), but I'd rather leave it alone so a dev can repro.

Comment: @DMA57361 good catch, didn't spot that ( about the revisions). And yes for the reasons that you have mentioned, I haven't touched the comment either

Comment: I get the same Oops! error trying to convert to comment also.

Comment: Automagically converted: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2892/convert-to-comment-results-in-oops-something-bad-happened-error/2893#2893

Comment: short answer [is short](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2892/convert-to-comment-results-in-oops-something-bad-happened-error/2893#2893)

Comment: Second try! http://meta.superuser.com/q/2892/94

Comment: this is beautiful, @MarcGravell

Comment: love all the ♦'s. :P

Comment: @studiohack hehe here's more ♦'s :p

Comment: @Sathya ♦ paarrrrttayyyyyyy! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm... yes, that data got a bit gobbled, didn't it.

I've deleted that post, and good news:

- the data-gobbling gremlin has been found and caged; deploy is in progress
- in future, you *won't see* posts like these - they will automatically become comments

For example, I'm about to add a second answer to this post, pointing at this one... here goes...